# How to find cumulative probability density function given the probability density function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

> Given probability density function
>
> $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 3x^2 &\mbox{for } 0 < x \le1 \\ 
> 0 & \mbox{otherwise }  \end{cases}$$
>
> Show that the **cumulative** probability density function $F$ corresponding to $f$ is given by
>   $$ F(x) = \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{for } x<0 \ \\ 
> x^3 & \mbox{for }0 \leq x \le1 \\1 & \mbox{for }x>1  \end{cases} $$

I know that the **probability** density function of a random variable $X$ is given by $$f(x)=f_X(x)=\frac{d}{dx}F(x) $$ , but that's about it. Help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Differentiate $F$ or integrate $f$ and see what happens.

Comment: @user251257 I understand that $\int 3x^2dx =x^3+C$, but here there are lots of 'pieces' and boundaries which i don't understand.

Comment: Terminology correction: it is called the cumulative **distribution** function, not density.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) at $x$ is just given by the integration of the PDF from $-\infty$ to $x$. If you want justification, you can look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248269/the-pdf-is-the-derivative-of-the-cdf-how-does-this-work).

Now, with this information, it is pretty easy to divide $F(x)$ and perform piecewise integration to get your answer.