# The effect of scaling arbitrary random varaible on its probability distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions

Is it true that for an arbitrary random variable $X$, the distribution of $\frac{X}{2}$ is simply horizontally squeezing the original distribution to half of the original size and stretching it vertically to double of the original size? I mean strictly speaking rather than just a hand-waving ilustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a continuous, real valued random variable with probability density function (PDF) $f_X$, and denote $Y:=X/2$.

We will compute the PDF of $Y$ $f_Y$, [which is given by](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248269/how-is-the-derivative-of-the-cdf-of-a-random-variable-x-its-pdf) the derivative of its CDF $F_Y$. For all $t\in\mathbb R$ we have :
$$F_Y(t) := \mathbb P(Y\le t) = \mathbb P(X/2\le t) = \mathbb P(X\le 2t) = F_X(2t) \tag1$$

Where $F_X$ is the CDF of $X$. It thus follows by differentiating $(1)$ w.r.t. $t$ and applying the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) that for all $t\in\mathbb R$ :
$$f_Y(t) =\frac{d}{dt}F_Y(t)  =  \frac{d}{dt}F_X(2t) = \color{red}{2}f_X(\color{blue}{2}t) $$

We thus see that, indeed, the PDF of $X/2$ is that of $X$  $\color{red}{\text{stretched vertically}} $ by a factor of $2$ and $\color{blue}{\text{squeezed horizontally}} $ by a factor of $2$.

Comment: super clear. thank you!